# How to get the last move to be displayed before moving onto new game?

Tags: java, android

I might need to tweak my logic with the below. Basically with a tic tac toe app I have developed, the problem is that the winning move is not displayed before the next game starts. I think it's because I check if two buttons are the same in any row, column or diagonal and the third square is empty then my program is like yes its a win for player or computer or draw.

How can I get the last move to be displayed on the board before the next game starts?

```
public class MainActivityPlayer1 extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private Button[][] buttons = new Button[3][3];

    private boolean playerOneMove = true;

    private int turnsCount;

    private int playerOnePoints;
    private int playerTwoPoints;

    private TextView textViewPlayerOne;
    private TextView textViewPlayerTwo;
    private TextView textViewPlayerOneTurn;
    private TextView textViewPlayerTwoTurn;
    private TextView textViewFooterTitle;

    Button selectButton;

    Random random = new Random();

    boolean firstComputerMove = false;

    int playerX = Color.parseColor("#e8e5e5");
    int playerO = Color.parseColor("#737374");


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_player1);

        Typeface customFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/ConcertOne-Regular.ttf");

        textViewPlayerOne = findViewById(R.id.textView_player1);
        textViewPlayerTwo = findViewById(R.id.textView_player2);
        textViewPlayerOneTurn = findViewById(R.id.textView_player1Turn);
        textViewPlayerTwoTurn = findViewById(R.id.textView_player2Turn);
        textViewFooterTitle = findViewById(R.id.footer_title);

        textViewPlayerOne.setTypeface(customFont);
        textViewPlayerTwo.setTypeface(customFont);
        textViewFooterTitle.setTypeface(customFont);


        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                String buttonID = "button_" + i + j;
                int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(buttonID, "id", getPackageName());
                buttons[i][j] = findViewById(resID);
                buttons[i][j].setOnClickListener(this);

                if (savedInstanceState != null) {
                    String btnState = savedInstanceState.getCharSequence(buttonID).toString();
                    if (btnState.equals("X")) {
                        buttons[i][j].setTextColor(playerX);
                    } else {
                        buttons[i][j].setTextColor(playerO);
                    }

                }

            }
        }

        Button buttonReset = findViewById(R.id.button_reset);
        buttonReset.setTypeface(customFont);
        buttonReset.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                resetGame();
            }
        });

        Button buttonExit = findViewById(R.id.button_exit);
        buttonExit.setTypeface(customFont);
        buttonExit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                backToMainActivity();
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if (!((Button) v).getText().toString().equals("")) {
            return;
        }

        turnsCount++;

        if (playerOneMove) {
            ((Button) v).setText("X");
            ((Button) v).setTextColor(playerX);
            isGameOver();
        }

    }

    public void isGameOver() {

        if (checkGameIsWon()) {
            if (playerOneMove) {
                player1Wins();
            } else {
                player2Wins();
            }
        } else if (turnsCount == 9) {
            draw();
        } else {
            playerOneMove = !playerOneMove;
            if (!playerOneMove) {
                final Handler handler = new Handler();
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        computerMove();
                    }
                }, 1000);
            }
        }
    }

    private void computerMove() {
        String[][] field = new String[3][3];
        List<Button> emptyButtons = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                field[i][j] = buttons[i][j].getText().toString();
                if (field[i][j].equals("")) {
                    emptyButtons.add(buttons[i][j]);
                }
            }
        }

        //IS COMPUTER GOING FIRST

        if (firstComputerMove == true){
            selectButton = emptyButtons.get(random.nextInt(emptyButtons.size()));
        }
        else {

            //TAKE MIDDLE SQUARE IF NOT TAKEN

            if (field[1][1].equals("")) {
                selectButton = buttons[1][1];
            }

            //FIRST ROW ACROSS

            else if (field[0][0] != "" && field[0][0].equals(field[0][1])
                    && field[0][2].equals("")) {
                selectButton = buttons[0][2];
            } else if (field[0][0] != "" && field[0][0].equals(field[0][2])
                    && field[0][1].equals("")) {
                selectButton = buttons[0][1];
            } else if (field[0][1] != "" && field[0][1].equals(field[0][2])
                    && field[0][0].equals("")) {
                selectButton = buttons[0][0];
            }

            //SECOND ROW ACROSS

            else if (field[1][0] != "" && field[1][0].equals(field[1][1])
                    && field[1][2].equals("")) {
                selectButton = buttons[1][2];
            } else if (field[1][0] != "" && field[1][0].equals(field[1][2])
                    && field[1][1].equals("")) {
                selectButton = buttons[1][1];
            } else if (field[1][1] != "" && field[1][1].equals(field[1][2])
                    && field[1][0].equals("")) {
                selectButton = buttons[1][0];
            }

            //THIRD ROW ACROSS

            else if (field[2][0] != "" && field[2][0].equals(field[2][1])
                    && field[2][2].equals("")) {
                selectButton = buttons[2][2];
            } else if (field[2][0] != "" && field[2][0].equals(field[2][2])
                    && field[2][1].equals("")) {
                selectButton = buttons[2][1];
            } else if (field[2][1] != "" && field[2][1].equals(field[2][2])
                    && field[2][0].equals("")) {
                selectButton = buttons[2][0];
            }

            //FIRST COLUMN DOWN

            else if (field[0][2] != "" && field[0][2].equals(field[1][2])
                    && field[2][2].equals("")) {
                selectButton = buttons[2][2];
            } else if (field[0][2] != "" && field[0][2].equals(field[2][2])
                    && field[1][2].equals("")) {
                selectButton = buttons[1][2];
            } else if (field[1][2] != "" && field[1][2].equals(field[2][2])
                    && field[0][2].equals("")) {
                selectButton = buttons[0][2];
            }

            //SECOND COLUMN DOWN

            else if (field[0][1] != "" && field[0][1].equals(field[1][1])
                    && field[2][1].equals("")) {
                selectButton = buttons[2][1];
            } else if (field[0][1] != "" && field[0][1].equals(field[2][1])
                    && field[1][1].equals("")) {
                selectButton = buttons[1][1];
            } else if (field[1][1] != "" && field[1][1].equals(field[2][1])
                    && field[0][1].equals("")) {
                selectButton = buttons[0][1];
            }

            //THIRD COLUMN DOWN

            else if (field[0][0] != "" && field[0][0].equals(field[1][0])
                    && field[2][0].equals("")) {
                selectButton = buttons[2][0];
            } else if (field[0][0] != "" && field[0][0].equals(field[2][0])
                    && field[1][0].equals("")) {
                selectButton = buttons[1][0];
            } else if (field[2][0] != "" && field[2][0].equals(field[1][0])
                    && field[0][0].equals("")) {
                selectButton = buttons[0][0];
            }

            //DIAGAONAL TOP RIGHT BOTTOM LEFT

            else if (field[2][0] != "" && field[2][0].equals(field[0][2])
                    && field[1][1].equals("")) {
                selectButton = buttons[1][1];
            } else if (field[2][0] != "" && field[2][0].equals(field[1][1])
                    && field[0][2].equals("")) {
                selectButton = buttons[0][2];
            } else if (field[1][1] != "" && field[1][1].equals(field[0][2])
                    && field[2][0].equals("")) {
                selectButton = buttons[2][0];
            }

            //DIAGAONAL TOP LEFT BOTTOM RIGHT

            else if (field[0][0] != "" && field[0][0].equals(field[2][2])
                    && field[1][1].equals("")) {
                selectButton = buttons[1][1];
            } else if (field[0][0] != "" && field[0][0].equals(field[1][1])
                    && field[2][2].equals("")) {
                selectButton = buttons[2][2];
            } else if (field[1][1] != "" && field[1][1].equals(field[2][2])
                    && field[0][0].equals("")) {
                selectButton = buttons[0][0];
            } else {
                selectButton = emptyButtons.get(random.nextInt(emptyButtons.size()));
            }
        }
        selectButton.setText("O");
        selectButton.setTextColor(playerO);
        firstComputerMove = false;
        turnsCount++;
        isGameOver();

    }

    private boolean checkGameIsWon() {
        String[][] field = new String[3][3];

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                field[i][j] = buttons[i][j].getText().toString();
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            if (field[i][0].equals(field[i][1])
                    && field[i][0].equals(field[i][2])
                    && !field[i][0].equals("")) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            if (field[0][i].equals(field[1][i])
                    && field[0][i].equals(field[2][i])
                    && !field[0][i].equals("")) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        if (field[0][0].equals(field[1][1])
                && field[0][0].equals(field[2][2])
                && !field[0][0].equals("")) {
            return true;
        }

        if (field[0][2].equals(field[1][1])
                && field[0][2].equals(field[2][0])
                && !field[0][2].equals("")) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    private void player1Wins() {
        playerOnePoints++;
        Toast.makeText(this, "Player 1 wins!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        updatePointsText();
        resetBoard();
    }

    private void player2Wins() {
        playerTwoPoints++;
        Toast.makeText(this, "Computer wins!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        updatePointsText();
        resetBoard();
        firstComputerMove = true;
        computerMove();
    }

    private void draw() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Draw!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        resetBoard();
        playerOneMove = !playerOneMove;
        switchPlayerTurn();
        if (!playerOneMove){
            firstComputerMove = true;
            computerMove();
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    private void updatePointsText() {
        textViewPlayerOne.setText("PLAYER 1:  " + playerOnePoints + " ");
        textViewPlayerTwo.setText("COMPUTER: " + playerTwoPoints + " ");
    }

    private void resetBoard() {

                for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                        buttons[i][j].setText("");
                    }
                }

                turnsCount = 0;
                switchPlayerTurn();
    }


    private void resetGame() {
        playerOnePoints = 0;
        playerTwoPoints = 0;
        turnsCount = 0;
        playerOneMove = true;
        updatePointsText();
        resetBoard();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

        outState.putInt("turnsCount", turnsCount);
        outState.putInt("playerOnePoints", playerOnePoints);
        outState.putInt("playerTwoPoints", playerTwoPoints);
        outState.putBoolean("playerOneMove", playerOneMove);
        switchPlayerTurn();

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                String buttonID = "button_" + i + j;
                Button btn = buttons[i][j];
                outState.putCharSequence(buttonID, btn.getText());
            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) { ;
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

        turnsCount = savedInstanceState.getInt("turnsCount");
        playerOnePoints = savedInstanceState.getInt("playerOnePoints");
        playerTwoPoints = savedInstanceState.getInt("playerTwoPoints");
        playerOneMove = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("playerOneMove");
        switchPlayerTurn();

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                String buttonID = "button_" + i + j;
                Button btn = buttons[i][j];
                savedInstanceState.putCharSequence(buttonID, btn.getText());

            }
        }

    }

    private void switchPlayerTurn(){
        if (playerOneMove){
            textViewPlayerOneTurn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            textViewPlayerTwoTurn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
        else{
            textViewPlayerOneTurn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            textViewPlayerTwoTurn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

    }

    private void backToMainActivity(){
        Intent intentMainActivity = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intentMainActivity);
    }

}
```

Comment: Starting a timer or a post delayed would do.

Comment: @greenapps This was something I tried to implement earlier with the post delayed but at no point was I able to pin point when to place that delay.

Comment: There where you call for a new game.

Comment: Ok I'll give a try, can you post where you put it in the code as your answer and I will update you. Trying now

Comment: Just try first.

Comment: It worked, I am sure I tried this before and it didn't work but I am proven wrong. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start a timer or do a delayed post there where you start a new game now.

Answer (score 0):

Your program seems to be a bit awkward. [Here](https://7th-stone.com/index.php?id=29) is a program that simulates the NSA May 2018 puzzle. The `won?` function there corresponds to Your `checkGameIsWon()` function.
I would take the logic and reprogram `checkGameIsWon()`:

- `wins` contains the 8 possible 3-in-a-row winning positions on the board
- if all 3 indexed positions on the board are not empty and are of the same type (**x** or **o**) the game is won
- usually **x** is player one